# x86 Assembly instruction

Tags: assembly

Today I was designing a poster for a friend that said 'eat (burger), sleep ("ZZZ"), code (</>), repeat'
For the 'repeat' part I want to use the assembly instruction 'EB', I know that "EB FE" will jump to the same line (infinite loop) but am I right in saying that "EB FB" will jump me back to the beginning of the poster?
If not how would I do that and is there a 'more nerdy' way of doing a repeat? (thats not a 'while loop')

Comment: IMO, hex offsets don't work as a joke/pun unless they say something when read as plaintext (as in e.g. 0xBADF00D). Anyway, to calculate the real offset you would need to know the length of the instructions `eat` and `sleep` and you can't since they're not real instructions :)

Comment: Ah fair enough, That makes sense. Any suggestions for a substitute?

Comment: `EB FB` will jump back 5 bytes, i.e. -5, relative to next instruction immediately after `EB FB`

Answer (score 4):

`EB FB` would jump 3 bytes back, relative to the start of the jump instruction.

**test.asm:**

```
start:
nop
nop
nop 
jmp start
```

```
C:\nasm>nasm -f bin -o test.com test.asm
C:\nasm>ndisasm test.com

00000000  90                nop 
00000001  90                nop
00000002  90                nop
00000003  EBFB              jmp short 0x0
```

Comment: Ah thank you! that answers my question but as '500-internal server error' pointed out, without knowing the length of the 'eat, sleep, code' instructions theres no way of knowing how far back to jump.. so I'm still open to suggestions for another way!